# Add lists inside dictionary to DataFrame as new columns

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Let's say I have the following pandas DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [0, 1, 2], 'y': [3, 4, 5], 'z': [6, 7, 8]})
     x   y   z
 0   0   3   6
 1   1   4   7
 2   2   5   8
```

And the following dictionary:

```
d = {'a': [10, 10, 10], 'b': [100, 100, 100]}
```

What's the best way to add the dictionary to the DataFrame to get the following:

```
     x   y   z    a    b
 0   0   3   6   10  100
 1   1   4   7   10  100
 2   2   5   8   10  100
```

This is what I've come up with so far but I feel like there has to be a better way:

```
df_bigger = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(d)], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `assign` with dictionary unpacking

```
df.assign(**d)

    x   y   z   a   b
0   0   3   6   10  100
1   1   4   7   10  100
2   2   5   8   10  100
```

Note that with `assign` as long as the length of the lists is consistent with the dataframe, then the indices are taken care of.

Comment: What does `**d` mean / do?

Comment: The ** unpacks the dictionary and passes it as keyword arguments to assign. That is precisely what is needed to add the extra columns

Answer (score 3):

You can use join(). And as @piRsquared mentioned in the comment, pass index as follows.

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(d, index = df.index))

    x   y   z   a   b
0   0   3   6   10  100
1   1   4   7   10  100
2   2   5   8   10  100
```

Comment: Plus one from me. Also, need to include df index in constructor otherwise will fail if df has non default

Comment: @piRSquared, thanks:) I did test it by changing the index of df and it returned all NaNs in a and b. You are awesome!

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to do this:

```
dataframe_dict = pd.DataFrame.to_dict(orient='dict')
d = {'a': [10, 10, 10], 'b': [100, 100, 100]}

new_dict = dict(dataframe_dict.items() + d.items())
```

BTW, I never used DataFrames, but here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html, it says you can convert a dataframe to dict, so i just converted it, and created a new dict with the other items included.

Answer (score 0):

```
#merge existing data with the new dict and re-construct a DF.
pd.DataFrame(dict(df.to_dict(orient='list'),**d))
Out[186]: 
    a    b  x  y  z
0  10  100  0  3  6
1  10  100  1  4  7
2  10  100  2  5  8
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16231518)